# Java catching terminal output

Tags: java, terminal, base64

i'm currently trying to write a Java file for de/encoding base64 in a linux shell. The method I have so far is:

```
public static String cmdExec(String Base64String) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException{
    String line;

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("openssl enc -base64 -d <<< " + Base64String);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
             while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            output += (line);
        }
        input.close();
        }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    return output;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting output although the command is working if I type it manually into the shell.
I know there's a Java Encoder since Java 8 and also the apache solution, but i'd really like to get it working via command line.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is the `exec` command correct? Does it work when you run the same command from the terminal? Are you sure it works without an absolute path to the executable? What does `<<<` do and does it work without an interpreter like `bash` ? Why do you split the command into some many String literals, making it hard to read?

Comment: All of Thilo's "whys" plus why don't you simply use the `base64` Linux command instead of `openssl`? Are you trying to redirect input with `<<<`? If so you could use the `-in` option to `openssl enc`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm not getting any errors and the exec command seems to work for me. Also it's working if type the command myself into the shell. I've found the openssl command as an alternative for e.g. echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode, because if I'm using the echo one, my output is QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode (although this is also working for me if i type it myself in the shell). You're right with the splitting of the command, sorry for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the child is not run in a shell, so the attempted redirection is literally treated as an argument to `openssl`. Therefore `openssl` complains that `<<<` is an invalid option. You can see this by capturing and printing the child's standard error via `p.getErrorStream()` in the same manner that you do for stdout. Also the child process' exit value is available with `p.exitValue()` - you should check that too.

Now, the `Base64String` argument is the base64 encoded text that you wish to decode, so you need to send that text as input to the child. You can get the child's stdin with `p.getOuputStream()`, and then write to the stream:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("openssl enc -base64 -d");
// Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("base64 -d");    // the base64 command also works
BufferedWriter toChild = new BufferedWriter(
                             new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
toChild.write(Base64String + "\n");
toChild.close();
```

Once you have closed the child's stdin you can read the decoded output using `p.getInputStream()` as you currently do. As mentioned above, you should check the child's exit value (non-zero means that an error occurred in the child), and collect the child's stderr so that it can be displayed if the exit value is non-zero.

One final thing, the command `base64 -d` also works, is usually present as a core linux utility, and doesn't require that `openssl` be installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! cmdLine is a String like "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" which i want to decode to (keeping that example) "Aladdin:open sesame". I've tried the steps mentioned but  System.out.println(output); is still printing nothing (newlines) instead of the expected phrase.

Comment: Well `<<<` will only work in a shell but `exec()` does not execute the command using a shell, so the redirection won't work. You need to write the encoded string to the child's standard input -  use `p.getOutputStream()` for that. I've updated my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: I hope that going through all these steps illustrates why it is a much better idea to use a pure Java solution for something as simple as Base64 encoding.

Comment: Thank you very much mhawke! That was exactly what I wanted to do:).

Answer (score -1):

maybe try with `Scanner`:

```
String output = "";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("openssl enc -base64 -d <<< "+cmdLine);
Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
while (s.hasNext()) {
  output += s.next();
}
s.close();
```